# Fedora: Adding a third monitor to the mix

Tags: linux, display, fedora

I have a dual head NVIDIA based video card. I have dual monitor running and it works perfectly. I would like to add another monitor and I'm wondering if the following would work.
Buy a "cheap" PCI card (no other PCIe slot available), then attach my third monitor to this video card. Fire up nvidia's control panel and pray that it sees the third monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I had just such an arrangement a couple of years ago. The "cheap" card was also an NVIDIA one (sorry can't remember the exact model). But it all worked fine and the NVIDIA software was able to control everything, including things like having some of the monitors rotated 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Try it! This will work!

I have it setup using Fedora and it recognized it on bootup! Go for it!